# How to plot barplots using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I was trying to create a barplot using ggplot but couldn't get the right result.
This is my data set:

[image]

I'm trying to create a barplot like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do (assuming your dataframe is called `d`):

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = continental_sum)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  labs(
   title = "Total Death Per Continent",
   y = "Total Death Count",
   x = ""
)
```

Comment: And next time please share a reproducible example of your code (rather than a screenshot) :)